# Can't install Jenkins 2nd time

Tags: jenkins

I'm making first steps with Jenkins.

It successfully installed the first time, but after adding GitHub access token and credentials and the following restart I could not log in.

To resolve that I disabled security, but was not able to create a new user (did not to work with security disabled), and after half-hour googling and struggle I decided to uninstall Jenkins, delete Jenkins data (from C:\Users\MY_USER\AppData\Local\Jenkins and C:\Program Files\Jenkins).

After uninstallation, I tried to install Jenkins again - it could not complete installation as it could not start the service. I realized that Jenkins service was still running.

So I deleted the content of both above-mentioned folders again, restarted windows, made sure there is no Jenkins service anymore and tried installation again.

Same problem: Jenkins can't start the service. I even tried to launch installer under Admin, the result is the same:

> Service 'Jenkins' (Jenkins) failed to start. Verify that you have
> sufficient privileges to start system services.

**Question:** What is the problem and how can I install Jenkins?

P.S. Jenkins version I'm trying to use is 2.273 and installing Jenkins under 'Admin' user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what was the cause of the problem, but the way I resolved it was:

- Initiate installation again and come to the point when installer complains about inability to start the service
- Once got the error message:

  - go to Windows Services and find Jenkins service
  - go to its Properties, open "Log On" tab
  - switch "Log on as" to "Local System account" (in my case it was specified account)
  - save changes by clicking "OK"
  - right click on Jenkins service again and "Start" it manually.

Comment: You should have chosen the account (user or local system) in the installer dialog. You really should not use local system - too privileged, security risk. So is Admin.  notes on [JENKINS-63477](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-63477). You may want to raise an issue about uninstalling causing issues on reinstall.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with this. For now, this is my local instance at home, with not a real production system. More for playing, so I guess, I'll let it go.